What type of patterns can you use with a preposition?
Im trying to learn syntactic patterns and I came across a webpage:
Subject → verb → indirect object → direct object
"The dog gave me the ball".
Keep in mind that objects of prepositions do not follow this pattern; e.g. "The dog gave the ball to me". Subject → verb → direct object →  indirect object
Does this mean you cannot use "the dog gave to me the ball" — isnt that Subject → verb →     indirect object  → direct object ??
Also I have read the phrases
"I put it in the box."
Subject → verb → preposition → direct object
"Who did you talk to?"
direct object → Subject → verb → preposition
Are there any other types of patterns I can use with prepositions? thanks

Preposition-like entities are used (according to traditional analysis: 'particles') in what are known sometimes as 'phrasal verbs', or 'multi-word verbs'. Thus 'He looked up the word in OED' uses the MWV 'look up'; it is unary, a single lexeme, synonym 'research'. But 'He looked up the stairs and saw a poodle' uses simplex verb (look') + prepositional phrase ('up the stairs'). // Prepositions are polysemous, having prototypical [spatial / temporal] ('He stood on the platform'), transparent metaphorical ('He is on the train') and peripheral, opaque metaphorical ('It is on fire') senses.

"Are there any other types of patterns I can use?" Sure, so many that they can't really all be listed here. And even some that are not common today might be found in older usages or poetry, where unusual word order (like "the dog gave to me the ball") is common.

Your use of "indirect object" does not match standard descriptions of English syntax.  An indirect object is something like "I gave the dog the ball"  "the dog" is an indirect object and "the ball" is a direct object of the verb "give".
In a sentence "The dog gave the ball to me",  "the ball" is the direct object, and "to me" is a prepositional phrase, not an object.  The meaning of this sentence is the same as the one with an indirect object, but the syntax is different. It achieves the same meaning with different syntax.
The position of prepositional phrases is complex and depends on the particular sentence. Often they are placed after the verb and any objects, sometimes they are placed before the subject or even in the middle of the sentence. Sometimes there is flexibility, sometimes the meaning depends on the placing of the phrase, sometimes you must place the phrase in a particular position.
For preposition phrases that indicate the recipient of a direct object in a "give" sentence, the preposition phrase is nearly always placed right after the direct object.  So "The dog gave the ball to me" and not "To me, the dog gave the ball" or "The dog, to me, gave the ball" nor "The dog gave to me, the ball".  These "incorrect" forms may occasionally be used for emphasis or to change the focus of the sentence, but all are marked.
"I put it in the box" is (Subject=I) (verb=put) (object = it) [pp in (object of in = the box)]. Unlike "give", there is no alternative with an indirect object when using the verb "put"
"Who did you talk to?"  is further modified by the fronting of the interrogative pronoun "who", and the inversion of the verb and subject. The verb "talk" has no direct object.  "Who" may be analysed as the object of "to".

"Your use of "indirect object" does not match standard descriptions of English syntax" - you are reffering to "the dog gave to me the ball"? The top 2 sentences are correct? thx

Aslo referring to "to the dog", you said is a prepositional phrase, but "dog" is still in an indirect object isnt it? I was under the impression that a prepositional phrase had to have an object. cheers

In the PP "to the dog",  the NP "the dog" is the object of the preposition "to".  It's not directly related syntactically to the verb and so isn't an object (direct or indirect) of the verb.  You are making a common mistake of mixing up syntax with semantics.   You are thinking about the meaning, and not the structure.  Now as a  Learner you are doing the right thing you should think about meaning and don't try to do syntactic analysis.  It doesn't help you learn to communicate in English very much.

The first two sentences are correct.  Your understanding of them is correct.  You know what they mean.  Your analysis is (according to my understanding of syntax) incorrect.  Does that matter if you understand what the sentences mean?

By the way, I've edited to make my examples match the question better.

" It's not directly related syntactically to the verb" — I'm sure I will get this shortly. When you say don't do "syntactic analysis", do you mean AT ALL or as one of the 1st methods of analysizing a sentence? i.e. for analysing a sentence, you #1 identify the type of sentence #2 identify the subject #3 identify the verb and predicate. etc. etc.— syntactic analysis comes further down the list. cheers

Native speakers don't do concious syntactic analysis, when speaking or writing.  It's not known if the categories "noun", "verb", "subject" etc map to any particular neurological process, and it's not demonstrated that "being good at creating a parse tree" is an effective way of learning a foreign language.  So when someone speaks to me I don't "identify the type of sentence"
